# Can't get favicon from instagram

Tags: c#, html, image, favicon

I need to retrieve favicon of instagram. Now my program can parse html code and retrieve the appropriate url of the icon: http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/d1f7ba7/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png.
But I can't read this icon from my program because the instagram puts some extra bytes in the beginning, the middle and the end of this file when my program tries to download it:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var iconBytes = wc.DownloadData(@"http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/d1f7ba7/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png");
var converter = new ImageConverter();
var image = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(iconBytes); // Crash here 'parameter is invalid'
```

I tried to save the png file from the web browser directly. Then I analyzed its content and came to conclusion that the bytes array which WebClient returns is almost identical but it contains 15 extra bytes in the beginning, 8 extra bytes in the end and 5 extra bytes in the middle of the array. I can easily clean this 'salt' from the beginning and the end based on knowledge of png format, but I have no idea how to remove the garbage from the middle of the array.

Could you please help me figure out how to download and process instagram favicon?

Comment: Using the webbrowser control, can you find it in the Images collection of the loaded Document and is it clean there?

Comment: Two things to investigate : the WebClient may expose some underlying HTTP stuff (like chunking). Look at these extra bytes and search for their meaning. Second clue : maybe the server sends different content based on user agent. Configure your WebClient to appear like your browser.

Answer (score 1):

This Google Service will return the image:

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.instagram.com
```

Example

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain= *Domain*
```